# Image and text not displaying on page

Tags: php, html, css

Im busy with an school command, and i need to play display and text on a page when you have fill in 2 forms on 2 different pages.

First page is kies_merk.html where you have to choose the merk (brand)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kies merk</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Auto selectie (Deel 1 van 3)</h3>
<p>Kies een automerk...</p>
<form name="form" action="kies_type.php" method="get">
    <select name="merk">
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Peugeot">Peugeot</option>
        <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
        <option value="Opel">Opel</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Second page is where you have to choose the type of the car:

```
<?php
  $formulier = '<p>Welk type wil je bekijken?</p><form name="form2" action="type_informatie.php" method="get"><select name="type"><option value="S40">S40</option><option value="S60">S60</option><option value="C70">C70</option><option value="S80">S80</option></select><input type="hidden" name="Merk" value="Volvo"><input type="submit" value="ok"/></form>'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kies merk</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Auto selectie (Deel 2 van 3)</h3>
<p>Kies een type...</p>


<?php
  $merk = ($_GET['merk']);
  if ($merk === Volvo) {
    echo $formulier;
  } else {
    echo "<p>Dit merk zit helaas nog niet in het 'systeem'...</p><a href='kies_merk.html'>Maak een andere keuze a.u.b</a>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

On the third page is the output, but there it goes wrong. It doesnt show the image, it only takes the first number out of the array. If i go to my browser to the image URL, it says for e.g. /S (not even .png extension). I think it goes wrong at the $type = $_GET['type'] part, but i dont know for sure. I hope someone can help me.
type_informatie.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kies merk</title>
  <style>
    img {
      height: 200px;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Auto selectie (Deel 3 van 3)</h3>
    <p>Je koos de volgende auto: <?php echo ($_GET['Merk']) . " " . ($_GET['type']) ?> </p>
    <?php


      $S40 = array('/S40.png', 'De S40: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut malesuada tincidunt est ut faucibus.');
      $S60 = array('/S60.png', 'De S60: Fusce eget quam in purus interdum tincidunt ultricies sit amet velit. Nulla pulvinar cursus malesuada.');
      $C70 = array('/C70.png', 'De C70: Aenean aliquam varius eros. Nam dictum, lorem a maximus gravida, odio risus pretium mi, vel convallis neque dui eget nisl. Quisque vestibulum vel lacus id congue.');
      $S80 = array('/S80.png', 'De S80: Nullam rutrum metus nec iaculis facilisis. Maecenas vitae hendrerit orci. Nulla sit amet dolor risus. Fusce accumsan augue nec leo congue, nec porta tellus semper.');

      $type = $_GET['type'];
      echo "<div>" . "<img src='$type[0]' alt='' />" . "</div>";
      echo "<p>$type[1]</p>"
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if ($merk === Volvo)` - undefined Volvo constant... http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - I'll spoonfeed you `if ($merk === 'Volvo')`

Comment: `print_r($_GET['type'])` to see what's in there. it's probably not an array

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think some versions of php are smart enough to assume he meant 'Volvo' because the form seems to be displaying for OP. Still dirty and needs fixin'

Comment: Maybe `$$type[0]`, then you refer to the array named like the type ( e.g.: If `$type = "S80"` you get `$S80[0]`, but I don't know if it works with arrays (`$$type` will get `$S80`)). Why don't you set the array, when you know $type `switch ($type) { case "S40": $myArr = array('/S40.png', 'De S40: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut malesuada tincidunt est ut faucibus.'); break; etc...`   and `echo "<div>" . "<img src='$myArr[0]' alt='' />" . "</div>";`

Answer (score 0):

`$type = $_GET['type'];` is going to hold the `value` of the selected `option` in your `select` named `type`

```
<select name="type"><option value="S40">
```

`$type[0]` is an array reference in `<img src='$type[0]' alt='' />` which is referencing the first character in the string, which happens to be `S` from `S40`

so you need to echo the whole thing, and probably add the `.png` extension since that's not in your form.

```
echo "<div>" . "<img src='$type.png' alt='' />" . "</div>";
```

---

if you look at your error logs, then you might also notice a notice

> Notice: Use of undefined constant Volvo - assumed 'Volvo' in thispage.php on line 6,000,042

You should clean up that assumption by explicitly changing `if ($merk === Volvo)` which uses a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), to `if ($merk === 'Volvo')` which uses a string.